# How does this dependently-typed boolean elimination function work?

Tags: lambda-calculus, dependent-types

In the companion code to [A Tutorial Implementation of a Dependently Typed Lambda Calculus](https://www.andres-loeh.de/LambdaPi/) 
 - [`prelude.lp`](https://www.andres-loeh.de/LambdaPi/prelude.lp) - there is a rather intimidating definition of a `boolElim` function that's not described in the paper itself:

```
let boolElim =
  ( \ m mf mt -> finElim ( nat2Elim (\ n -> Fin n -> *)
                                    (\ _ -> Unit) (\ _ -> Unit)
                                    (\ x -> m x)
                                    (\ _ _ _ -> Unit) )
                         ( nat1Elim ( \ n -> nat1Elim (\ n -> Fin (Succ n) -> *)
                                                      (\ _ -> Unit)
                                                      (\ x -> m x)
                                                      (\ _ _ _ -> Unit)
                                                      n (FZero n))
                                    U mf (\ _ _ -> U) )
                         ( \ n f _ -> finElim ( \ n f -> nat1Elim (\ n -> Fin (Succ n) -> *)
                                                                  (\ _ -> Unit)
                                                                  (\ x -> m x)
                                                                  (\ _ _ _ -> Unit)
                                                                  n (FSucc n f) )
                                              ( natElim
                                                  ( \ n -> natElim
                                                             (\ n -> Fin (Succ (Succ n)) -> *)
                                                             (\ x -> m x)
                                                             (\ _ _ _ -> Unit)
                                                             n (FSucc (Succ n) (FZero n)) )
                                                  mt (\ _ _ -> U) )
                                              ( \ n f _ -> finElim
                                                             (\ n f -> natElim
                                                                         (\ n -> Fin (Succ (Succ n)) -> *)
                                                                         (\ x -> m x)
                                                                         (\ _ _ _ -> Unit)
                                                                         n (FSucc (Succ n) (FSucc n f)))
                                                             (\ _ -> U)
                                                             (\ _ _ _ -> U)
                                                             n f )
                                              n f )
                         2 )
  :: forall (m :: Bool -> *) . m False -> m True -> forall (b :: Bool) . m b
```

The type indicates its behaviour (an if-else), but I can't make any headway with the definition. Can someone break it down for me?

Comment: I think the code is a bit long to ask about in a stackexchange post. Is there a way to shorten the code to just the part you don't get?

Comment: @6005 I don't really get any of it

Comment: If I understand correctly this encodes Bool as Fin 2. I had a similar question a while ago, it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63728749/coq-induction-principles-for-void-unit-and-bool-from-nat-and-fin